# Why cant i import @WithMockUser to my test

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to do an authentication test with @With Mock User but it is refusing to import to my test class in spring boot . This is the class configuration

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AdminPortalApplication.class)
public class BookControllerTest {
```

@WithMockUser not able to import ,its red in color showing that spring boot does not recognize it, I used this dependency and property

```
<spring-security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>


       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Keeps saying cannot resolve symbol @WithMockUser

Comment: I presume this: "it is refusing to import to my test class" means that the `WithMockUser` class cannot be found on your project's classpath? If so, are you sure that a version of spring-security >=4 is on your classpath?

Comment: I meant this org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUserSecurityContextFactory Is not importing at all

Comment: You n eed to add `spring-security-test` as a test dependency.

Comment: Add testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test' should do the trick

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try fresh dependency. I just solved such issue with this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Remove the `version` as Spring Boot manages this and you are now risking in pulling a different version leading to all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Add an import statement for the library:

```
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
```

And declare a dependency in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That won't help as `@WithMockUser` is part of `spring-security-test` which isn't part of either of the starters.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing gradle to refresh your dependencies:

```
gradle --refresh-dependencies
```